# Как найти файлы на хостинге по первой части имени?

Tags: файлы, php

Доброго всем времени суток, господа! Нужен совет php гуру.

Есть на сайте директория tmp, внутри файлы, у которых известны имена (какое откуда), но не написаны расширения. Алгоритм такой, знаем первую часть имени - нужно найти есть ли файлы начинающиеся на это имя, и есть ли вообще, скажем начинается на  f931992748863024fda1b647080e8ffa (я так подозреваю что в прошлом это был session_id, но не суть)

Вот подскажите, как найти все файлы, которые начинаются на указанное имя? (их может быть несколько, может быть 1, а может и не быть) . `file_exists()`, к сожалению, требует точного совпадения. Вторая часть файлов обычно [_1.txt](http://_1.txt), _5.docx ... в таком формате, т.е. подчеркивание, цифра, точка, и какое то расширение. Очень хотелось бы получить ответ на php

p.s. формировать массив о содержимом каталога, и потом его перебирать - думаю не выход, т.к. конкретно у меня в каталоге более 10тыс файлов. Это займет много времени.

Comment: Походит на загрузку файлов:)

Comment: Походит, но тем не менее это поиск, когда известна первыя часть имени. atnartur, поможешь с кодом? 8-)

Comment: Вдогонку: формирование массив с 10к строк и его перебор не только долго, но и съест кучу памяти.

Comment: `ls **/somefile*`

Comment: полный пример был бы еще красноречивее 8-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
$dir = opendir($path);
$string_to_search='f931992748863024fda1b647080e8ffa';

while(($file = readdir($dir)) !== false)
{
    $a[] = strstr($file,$string_to_search);
}
print_r($a);
closedir($dir);
```

Comment: спасибо, то, что нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. это единственный ответ, и он работает, я немного модернизировал.

```
<?
// где - откроем
$dir = opendir("tmp");

//начинается на
$string_to_search='f931992748863024fda1b647080e8ffa';

// ищем
$mass_sas[] = "";
while(($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
    $mass_sa = strstr($file,$string_to_search);
    if($mass_sa != "") {
        $mass_sas[] = $mass_sa;
    }
}

// где - закроем
closedir($dir);

// если охота посмотреть что вышло
echo "<pre>";
print_r($mass_sas);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```